# Use Var from For Loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm sorry I'm really new to Java, I'm working on friends project. I seem to be struggling with this one. I'm trying to use a really simple for-loop to iterate through several variables that I get from another class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) { // Test and Loop
    myarr.add(anotherclass.SVAR+i);
}
```

I'm not sure why they were not originally put into an Array (maybe because its easier to access them as strings?). In any case they are set like SVAR0, SVAR1 up to SVAR7. How can I do this? When I have my SVAR+i, it says SVAR is not defined, which makes sense because it's not.

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't dynamically construct a reference to a variable / field etc. like that. The compiler needs an explicit reference.

You may wish to use [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), however, to derive the name, and then introspect on your object to find that field and retrieve the value. [Here'](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ObjectReflectiongetfieldvalue.htm)s a simple example to illustrate how you'd do this.

However I think a better object/field structure may be more appropriate (depending on your use case etc.)

Comment: Re. last paragraph: I.e. an array.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the variables with an array, or unroll the loop. What you want is possible, but only at great expense through VM introspection.